# How do I prepare my SIM card for SIM800L GPRS GSM module?

Tags: sim, module

Im trying to send a SMS message using the SIM800L GPRS GSM module.

I know this might sound stupid but, do I need to load my SIM first before it can send SMS message?

If possible, can I just pay after it sends the message without load balance beforehand?

Comment: how is this an electronics design question? ... call your provider ... see if they laugh

Comment: Ah??? Ask your network provider if they give free SMS? How do we know.

Comment: This should be no different that sending an SMS from a phone using the same SIM. It depends on the wireless provider.

Comment: Yes it is a stupid question, and I'm ridiculed by posting it to this thread. Im gonna laugh